# MAP Data More detailed for Airports Simulations

Tags: openstreetmap

I am looking for  a map api that would provide data such as this as you can see from this diagram. Little nav map adds the following I need to be able to replicate the same In my apps but I dont see a common format or much information around the process I have been using gmap with some success in that I have placed my plane on the map at the lat and long of the aiport but I need the below information to be added.

It was suggested I posted here in relation to this as I tried on other exchanges.

https://github.com/judero01col/GMap.NET/issues

1. Runway Numbers
2. ILS Detail the green aprons of ils
3. Aiport runway lengths

[image]